# Why my website mp3 player does not work?

Tags: php, html

Hi I have a problem with my music song website. I'm uploading a mp3 song from my computer and want to play it on my websites. But don't know why the mp3 file name doest not appear in the player src attribut.

Can someone able to help me out ?

```
<body>
<div id="main_container">
<form method="post" action='exercice.php' id="form1">
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" onChange="submitForm();">            
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files'])){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], "uploaded/");
}
$src = isset($_FILES['files']['name'])?$_POST['files']['name']:'';  
?>      
<object id="MediaPlayer1" width="800" height="500" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"           codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
        standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
        <param id="fileName" name="FileName" value='uploaded/<?php echo $src; ?>' />
        <param name="AutoStart" value="false" />
        <param name="DefaultFrame" value="mainFrame" />
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0" />
        <param name="ShowPositionControls" value="0" />
        <param name="showcontrols" value="0" />
        <param name="ShowAudioControls" value="0" />
        <param name="ShowTracker" value="0" />
        <param name="EnablePositionControls" value="0" />


        <!-- BEGIN PLUG-IN HTML FOR FIREFOX-->
        <embed  type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
            src='uploaded/<?php echo $src; ?>' align="middle" width="800" height="500" defaultframe="rightFrame"
             id="MediaPlayer2" />
        </object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($src)`?

Comment: @DaveChen's comment could be the way to go, although I'm struggling to understand in what situation you would want to upload and play, particularly via embed where perhaps HTML5 audio would be a cleaner method.

Comment: I saw `$src = isset($_FILES['files']['name'])?$_POST['files']['name']:'';`, it looks like you can only see the file's src once per upload.

Comment: The thing I want to do is upload an mp3 and play it on the player this is it. But when I print $src it is empty. Don't know why

Comment: @DaveChen no $src is empty the problem is from $_FILE. the file input only give you the file name. I will need that input file give me the whole path of the path pour doing it in JS